# Dura Ace 7800 rear mech cable fixing plate replacement

Tags: shimano

I can't get the rear mech cable fixing plate for a Dura Ace 7800 derailleur part Y5V598040 in the UK is there a substitute part I can use?

Comment: That part number looks correct - if your LBS can't get it from the wholesaler, try another LBS.   I can't identify a substitute.

Comment: Thanks Criggie I'll keep trying that angle, I was hoping to find another part number that would also work, mine snapped unfortunately.

Comment: From a web search, it looks like a generic part that appears on many RDs.Some LBS may have something similar in their broken bits bin, alternatively a bike repair commune.